# Comparing data of payments

Tags: c++, arrays

At my work we have two systems, one that collects the customers payments automatically every month. And one that manages the memberships of those customers. Sadly our outdated technology doesn’t communicate to each other so we don’t know if a customer actually paid for their membership without manually auditing them.

I’ve been put in charge of this process and boy does it take awhile to do.

I have limited knowledge of C++ and was looking into maybe writing a program to do the comparisons for me.

I have two ideas on how to implement this, and was wondering what you guys thought. If these would be best or if it’s even possible or if there’s a better solution?

Current Setup: We have a list of all members in excel, with how much each should be paying, we then go through the actual money collected and check to make sure everyone’s payment went through and was processed and not declined.

Option 1: have a multi-dimensional array of strings. Read the excel file into this array it would have three Columns, first name, last name, amount they should be paying. This would be put in alphabetical order to help with the searching. I would then export the transactions in css file format and read each line one at a time. When it reads a line it would search the array for the same first and last name. Once found it would take the amount paid confirm it said processed and not declined and if so would subtract it from the customers amount they should be paying. In the end if every customers amount they should be paying is equal to 0 then everyone paid.

Option 2: is similar to option 1 just instead of using a multidimensional array it would use two css files. And not put the items into the array at the start.

Thoughts? Is this a smart way to combat this problem? I’m a newbie programmer so I’m just looking for suggestions/advice.

Comment: It will probably cost a lot less to buy something. You can hack something out, but you're playing with money and people get really weird around money. They take the mistakes made while you're knocking the bugs out of the system really, really seriously. You'll have to take your time and make sure it's right, and depending on your value to your organization, the opportunity costs and the time spent on the manual process while getting it right plus the time spent checking your results against the manual process could be killer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions would work, but are suited for small datasets. I don't now what your constraints are, but I think that a more elegant solution would be to setup a database on the first system first(instead of the excel file). 
Are you allowed to create a database? How many customers are in the excel file?

Comment: Around 500 customers and growing around 700 customers a year in the location I’m in. There are 5 other locations with upwards of 1,000 customers, but we are all separate. From my understanding most of the other locations do similar, either with excel or printing out all the lists and doing it on paper and pen. I’d love set up a database, but the owners of the company are stringent in there ways. But now that I think about it, don’t see why I could just have a local database and import all the data in and use it to compare. Thanks for the thought!